# How to remove all whitespace and ASCII elements like "\n" from my HTML in Rust?

Tags: text, rust

I am writing something to extract product data from Amazon but I am not sure on how to normalize the whitespace in the HTML.

```rust
fn parse_html(html: std::string::String) {
    let fragment = Html::parse_fragment(&html);
    let product_title = Selector::parse(".s-line-clamp-2").unwrap();

    for title in fragment.select(&product_title) {
        let title_txt = title.text().collect::<Vec<_>>();
        println!("{:?}", title_txt);
    }
}
```

This works but the data i get is like this `["\n    \n    \n        \n\n\n\n\n", "\n    \n        \n            \n                ", "Men\'s Sneakers", "\n            \n        \n        \n    \n", "\n\n    \n"]`

I only want this: `["Men\'s Sneakers"]`

Comment: how about this ? https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=58bd341a93f64fa7407ca83982652a0d

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`trim`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.str.html#method.trim) to remove whitespace from the ends of strings and [`filter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.filter) to remove empty strings from your vector:

```
let title_txt = title
    .text()
    .map(|s| s.trim())
    .filter(|s| !s.is_empty())
    .collect::<Vec<_>>();
```